# iPhone/iPod Touch App Review Sites and Payola

Tags: iphone, ipod-touch, app-store-connect

Some of the iPhone/iPod Touch app review sites require developers to pay them to have a review posted. This raises obvious concerns about the independence and objectivity of the reviews.  (See [this Wired article](http://www.wired.com/gadgetlab/2010/03/app-store-payola/) for more information.) Requiring payment for product reviews is not illegal, so the only way to turn back this trend is for consumers to ignore these sorts of reviews.

So, I would like to have a list of app review sites, along with a note as to whether they charge for reviews, or have any other conflicts of interest.  Vote up the ones that you find most useful.

If you are a developer who has been asked to pay a fee by one of these sites, please provide details.

I want to keep this list focused on apps for iPhone and iPod Touch.  If you want to list review sites for other devices, please create another question.

Comment: Good question. Maybe better for Stack Overflow though...I'm not sure.

Comment: The intended audience for this list is iPhone users, not developers.

Comment: As a developer I completely ignore those sites: from what I've seen they rarely have more than a handful of visitors and site quality tends to be quite poor. Based on the fact that a review on a well-respected site isn't likely to sell many copies, paying for reviews is insane. One app of mine got a 4.5 (out of 5) mice review on MacWorld -- not the hottest review site, but well-respected with a lot of traffic -- and I sold maybe 10 extra copies as a result. Definitely not worth paying for.

Answer (score 2):

TheiPhoneAppReview.com and AppCraver.com are mentioned by the Wired article as sites that ask programmers to pay fees.